# Why this set is closed?(about irreducible topological spaces)

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be irreducible topological spaces and put any topology on $ X \times Y$ inducing the given topology on the images $\{x\} \times Y$ of $Y$ and $X \times \{y\}$ of $X$. Then $X \times Y$is irreducible.

I have a question about the part of the proof of this lemma:

Say $X\times Y = S\cup T$ ($S,T$ closed)

Let $s_y : X \to X\times Y$ be the map $x \mapsto (x,y)$.

Then
$S' := \bigcap_y s_y^{-1}(S) = \{x|(x,y)\in S,$ all $y\} = \{x|\{x\}\times Y\subset S \}$

Then, How do I show $S'$ is closed set?

I know that projection map is not always closed map, so it seems strange for me.

Comment: Is this from somewhere? I was wondering if there is any more context here. Meaning are you confident these are the correct steps and you are just missing why $S'$ is known to be closed?

Comment: This is from a book about algebraic geometry. S' is defined like this in the book and the author is saying it is closed.

Comment: The **inverse** image of a closed set by a continuous function is closed.

Comment: Why $s_y$ is continuous?